# Помогите увидеть ошибку пожалуйста

Tags: javascript, методы, перебор

Задача: Создайте функцию sumOfLeasts, которая возвращает сумму двух положительных самых маленьких чисел массива, в котором минимум 4 положительных целых числа. Дробных чисел не предусмотрено.
Мой код:

```
const sumOfLeasts = (arr) => {
      return arr.filter(i => i > 0).arr.sort((a,b) => {
      `${(a> b ? 1 : -1)}`;
      return newSortArr.reduce((a,b) => arr[0] + arr[1],0);
   };
};
console.log(sumOfLeasts([19, 5, 42, 2, 77]))
```

логика:

1. фильтрую массив, оставляю все положительные элементы
2. сортирую от меньшего к большему
3. вывожу сумму первых двух элементов

Не пойму, где ошибка в синтаксисе. Наверное можно упростить до одной строки, но я пока в двух разобраться не могу.

Comment: `${(a> b ? 1 : -1)}` - А вот этим вы что хотели достичь? Это же просто формирование строки...

Comment: был вариант return добавить в начало. хотел добиться сортировки и возврата через колбек

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
const sumOfLeasts = (arr) => {
    let positiveArr = arr.filter(i => i > 0);
    positiveArr.sort((a,b) => a - b);
    return positiveArr[0] + positiveArr[1];
};
console.log(sumOfLeasts([19, 5, 42, 2, 77]));
```

В строке с фильтром, вам нужно присвоить результат фильтрации переменной, и еще нужно использовать метод sort на массиве, а не на результате фильтрации.

Другой способ:

```
function sumOfLeasts(arr) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);  // сортируем массив по возрастанию
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) { // проходим по массиву два раза
    if (arr[i] > 0) { // если элемент положительный
      sum += arr[i]; // добавляем его к сумме
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(sumOfLeasts([19, 5, 42, 2, 77]));
```

Можно еще так:

```
function sumOfLeasts(arr) {
    let minArr = arr.filter(i => i > 0).sort((a, b) => a - b).slice(0,2) // сортируем и фильтруем массив и выбираем 2 минимальных значения
    return minArr.reduce((a,b) => a+b) // суммируем минимальные значения и возвращаем 
}
console.log(sumOfLeasts([19, 5, 42, 2, 77]));
```

или даже вот так:

```
function sumOfLeasts(arr) {
    let positiveArr = arr.filter(i => i > 0);
    return Math.min(...positiveArr) + Math.min(...positiveArr.filter(i => i > Math.min(...positiveArr)));
}
console.log(sumOfLeasts([19, 5, 42, 2, 77]));
```

Comment: Второй и 4й примеры работают с ошибкой.

Comment: Спасибо! очень расширяет кругозор такие разные варианты решения!

Answer (score 1):

Каждый из представленых методов массивов(кроме reduce) возвращает массив, поэтому можно организовать цепочку вызовов.

```js
    const sumOfLeasts = (arr) => {
      return arr
        .filter(i => i > 0) // Фильтруем массив
        .sort((a, b) => a - b) // Сортируем
        .slice(0, 2) // Оставляем 2 первых элемента
        .reduce((acc, it) => acc += it, 0); // считаем сумму
    };
    console.log(sumOfLeasts([19, 5, 42, 2, 77, -2]));
```

Подробнее про [методы массивов](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ваш код имеет несколько синтаксических ошибок и недостатков в логике:
   В строке return arr.filter(i => i > 0).arr.sort((a,b) => { вы используете .arr после функции filter, но не должны. Это должно быть только return arr.filter(i => i > 0).sort((a,b) => {
2. В строке ${(a> b ? 1 : -1)} вы используете шаблонную строку, но не нужно, это должно быть только (a> b ? 1 : -1)
3. В строке return newSortArr.reduce((a,b) => arr[0] + arr[1],0); вы используете переменную newSortArr, которая не объявлена в коде. Это должно быть return arr.reduce((a,b) => arr[0] + arr[1],0);
4. В строке return arr.reduce((a,b) => arr[0] + arr[1],0); вы используете arr[0] + arr[1] в качестве аргумента функции reduce, но это не должно быть так, должно быть a + b
5. В целом, ваша функция не возвращает сумму двух положительных самых маленьких чисел массива, как указано в задаче, потому что вы используете функцию reduce для вычисления суммы первых двух элементов массива, вместо того чтобы использовать индексы 0 и 1 для получения значений и сложения их.

Я предлагаю следующий код для решения задачи:

```
const sumOfLeasts = (arr) => {
    const sortedArr = arr.filter(i => i > 0).sort((a,b) => a - b);
    return sortedArr[0] + sortedArr[1];
};
console.log(sumOfLeasts([19, 5, 42, 2, 77]))
```

Этот код фильтрует массив, оставляя только положительные числа, сортирует их от меньшего к большему, и возвращает сумму первых двух элементов отсортированного массива.

Comment: Спасибо! очень подробно все объяснили!